# Microservices Integration Test Suite using Cucumber BDD

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, microservices, bdd, cucumber-jvm

Basically I want some advice on designing integration test suite for QA using Cucumber BDD in a microservice-integration application environment. 
Should QA maintain a separate code base and github repository for their test suite or its better to have the code residing inside each applications code base?

I am building an integration testsuite using cucumber BDD to test an enterprise applications platform. Each application in this platform has many microservices(built in springboot) and integration apps(Apache camel and fuse). Currently I have the test suite built for each project in the eclipse IDE(in the sense each micro service and integration app has its own code base in src/main folder and I have cucumber tests for each of them in the corresponding src/test folder). But I see these as system test rather than integration tests. When an app is deployed only its tests will be triggered in jenkins pipeline and cant run tests for a dependent app or service from its domain due to access restrictions. 
So what I am thinking is let QA team create and maintain a separate test application for their tests in a standalone repository rather than maintaining in each application level for integration tests and integrate it in Jenkins pipeline and trigger the features needed for each app using proper cucumber tags after deployment of the main app.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: anyone has any suggestions on building a microservices+integration apps test suite on cucumber-java?